# Java EE/Hibernate pull data from database and by persisting they are detached

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am new to Java EE.
My problem is to persist data that include data I pulled befor from database. It always say the data are deteched (i know pulling data from database is probelmatic but how could i do this without?).

This is what i have:

I have three Entitys: Game, Genre and Publisher

Game:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Game extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "game_genre", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "game_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id") })
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<Genre>();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="publisher_id")
    private Publisher publisher;


    @NotNull(message = "Bitte Namen hinzufügen")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + this.genres.toString() + this.publisher.toString();
    }
}
```

Genre:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Genre extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Game> games = new HashSet<Game>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

Publisher:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Publisher extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="publisher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Set<Game> games = new HashSet<Game>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

in my AbstractDao

```
@Override
public void create(final T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
}

@Override
public void update(final T t) {
    this.em.merge(t);
}
```

and the findAll() Method for every entity Dao

```
@Override
public List<Game> findAll() {

    final TypedQuery<Game> query = getEm().createQuery(
            "Select a FROM " + Game.class.getSimpleName() + " a", Game.class);

    return query.getResultList();

}
```

My Manager:

```
manager is an instance of GameManagerBo:

@Stateless
@ManagedBean(name = "manager")
public class GameManagerBo implements GameManager {

    @Inject
    private Dao<Game> gameDao;
    @Inject
    private Dao<Genre> genreDao;
    @Inject
    private Dao<Publisher> publisherDao;

    @Override //Same for Genre and Publisher
    public void saveGame(Game game) {
        if (game.getId() == null) {
            this.gameDao.create(game);
        } else {
            this.gameDao.update(game);
        }
    }

    @Override //Same for Genre and Publisher
    public List<Game> readGames() {
        return this.gameDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher getPublisherByName(String publisherName) {
        List<Publisher> publishers = publisherDao.findAll();
        Publisher foundPublisher = new Publisher();

        for (Publisher publisher : publishers) {
            if(publisher.getName().equals(publisherName)){
                foundPublisher = publisher;
            }
        }

        return foundPublisher;
    }
}
```

And here I call the function: createGame() that includes:

```
private void createGame(String name, String genreName, String publisherName) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setName(name);

    Genre genre = new Genre();
    genre.setName(genreName);

    Publisher publisher;

    if (manager.getPublisherByName(publisherName).getId() == null) {
        publisher = new Publisher();
        publisher.setName(publisherName);
    } else {
        publisher = manager.getPublisherByName(publisherName);
    }

    Set<Game> games = new HashSet<Game>();
    games.add(game);

    game.setPublisher(publisher);
    games.addAll(publisher.getGames());

    publisher.setGames(games);

    manager.savePublisher(publisher);
    manager.saveGame(game);
    manager.saveGenre(genre);
}
```

first time when I run this function all is fine. The data get persistet to database. But if I run it a secound time i get this error:

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: de.fhb.rangam.data.Publisher

and some other long stuff, but it is not important.

what i dont get is why the game get Persiste and the Genre. The Published should get updated?
 What ever i get the Error, pls help!

Sorry if there is already an answer out there, i did not find it and just ask after i take about 2days to find a solution by crawling the internet.

Comment: When I pull a object from the database it is detached. And the problem is that I give a reference to the object I am creating in the Session. 

like: 

      publisher = manager.getPublisherByName(publisherName);

but this is totally wrong... i have to copy the object and don't give the reference to it.
i should do this:

      Publisher tmpPub = manager.getPublisherByName(publisherName);
      publisher.setName(tmpPub.getName());
      publisher.setId(tmpPub.getId());
      publisher.setGames(tmpPub.getGames());

just so easy....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While it's laudable to include the code to reproduce your problem, my initial reaction was just "what?" because your example is waay to long. Funny thing is: you don't include the *relevant* code, ie the `save` methods that are throwing the error. What I've learned from JPA: you almost *always* want to use `merge()`, but remember the updated entity will be **returned** by the call (your dao swallows that value).

Comment: the save is there :D Yes I know its to long, but I did not know what is really important for the Problem.

Comment: Ah, i missed the comment about the others being the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge can also insert or update.. In your case i think it will be better to remove the condition `if (game.getId() == null)` and just always call `update` which will insert and update..

The diffrences are:

Persist takes an entity instance, adds it to the context and makes that instance managed (ie future updates to the entity will be tracked).

Merge creates a new instance of your entity, copies the state from the supplied entity, and makes the new copy managed. The instance you pass in will not be managed (any changes you make will not be part of the transaction - unless you call merge again).

Hope that helps

Comment: this is exact what helped me :)